# ElasticSearch 6 on 2.2.8 - Notice: Undefined index: magento2_product_1_v1

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

When attepting to index Catalog Search Fulltext I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: magento2_product_1_v1 in /app/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch-6/Model/Client/Elasticsearch.php on line 168
```

If I drop the ElasticSearch "magento2" prefix in the Magento admin config, I gut an "Unkown Error: null" exception from ElasticSearch.

On the frontend I am seeing:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[]},"status":503}
```

I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting this. I'm happy to provide more info to anyone willing to guide me here.

Comment: Have you Setup Elastic Search in the Server ?
Have you Indexed the Search ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the elasticsearch service is running? I am sure Magento 2.2.8 doesn't support Elasticsearch 6 they added support for it in 2.3.1. This could be the reason.

Comment: It is running. And, testing connectivity in the Magento Admin catalog config returns success.